# ggplot R 2 y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this r code in ggplot to do a plot

```
ggplot(ab,aes(x=pk1)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.5, position= 
position_dodge(0.5), color="black",fill="cadetblue4")+ ggtitle("Histogram of
PK1")+labs( x="PK1", y="Number of
Observations")+geom_density(aes(y=0.5*..count..))+
scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,10,0.5))
```

I want to have a separate y-axis on the right side with the actual values of the PDF rather than doing `aes(y=0.5*..count..)` to the original plot to make the curve fit. I want both the histogram and density curve on the same plot.

Comment: Try looking at the posts here! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/plot-with-2-y-axes-one-y-axis-on-the-left-and-another-y-axis-on-the-right

Comment: Yes, but that is still 2 separate plots. I need both on the same plot.

Comment: look at the one with 31 comments, it shows you how to add a second axis to your plot...and the one by Alessandro Jacopson shows you how to place two plots.

Comment: ...as does the one by tstenner. There's a lot of good answers there. If you can't get them working, edit your question to show your attempts and we'll help you debug.